# Cartesian Product with VBA

Tags: vba, product, cartesian

How do I add a third and fourth range/array to the following code?

```
Sub cartesianproduct()
Dim startrange As Range

range1 = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please Select First Range", Type:=8)
range2 = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please Select Second Range", Type:=8)


Set startrange = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please select where you want to put it", Type:=8)
array1 = [range1]
array2 = [range2]


startrange.Select
For i = 1 To UBound(array1)
    For x = 1 To UBound(array2)
        z = z + 1
        ActiveCell.Offset(z, 0).Value = array1(i, 1)
        ActiveCell.Offset(z, 1).Value = array2(x, 1)
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I need to add range3, range4 and array1, array2 and not sure what to do under startrange.select...

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub cartesianproduct()
Dim startrange As Range

range1 = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please Select First Range", Type:=8)
range2 = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please Select Second Range", Type:=8)
range3 = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please Select Third Range", Type:=8)


Set startrange = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please select where you want to put it", Type:=8)
array1 = [range1]
array2 = [range2]
array3 = [range3]


startrange.Select
For i = 1 To UBound(array1)
    For x = 1 To UBound(array2)
    For y = 1 To UBound(array3)
        Z = Z + 1
        ActiveCell.Offset(Z, 0).Value = array1(i, 1)
        ActiveCell.Offset(Z, 1).Value = array2(x, 1)
        ActiveCell.Offset(Z, 2).Value = array3(y, 1)
    Next
Next
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.